# Failure to overwrite hosts file with batch file

Tags: batch-file, hosts

I am attempting to clear all the contents of the hosts file with a batch script

here's my code:

```
@echo off 
cd %SYSTEMDRIVE%:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
takeown /f hosts
icacls hosts /grant %username%:w
echo > hosts
```

the hosts file appears unaffected after batch execution. what should I change?

Comment: What OS?  Check that you run your script as an admin.

Comment: Windows7 and yes tried as Admin

Comment: A wild guess: maybe Windows is just restoring the file directly after it's overwritten.

Comment: Your anti-virus could be protecting the `hosts` file also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I have found so. not really sure why it works, but it does, mostly

```
@echo off 
takeown /f C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
icacls C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts /grant %username%:w
echo # > C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
echo.
echo.
ipconfig /flushdns
echo.
echo.
echo All sites restored!
pause
```

If I attempt to open a new browser, it works great. If I have a browser currently open, It does not work. Any suggestions for that?

(using Chrome)